# Highcharts applying custom style to context button using css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I have a large set of Highcharts graphics that all use the exporting.js library for downloading in various formats.  I would like to customize the context button on these charts to match the native styles of the application.

Although I have found several examples of how to achieve this within the confines of the Highcharts chart-level script (i.e. [THIS EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/hq93c/) ) it seems rather repetitive to implement these styles in every chart knowing that I have a large set to be affected.

I realize this could potentially be achieved using a global theme in Highcharts, however I am still limited by the configuration options of the library itself.

For instance this would be the suggested path:

```
var chartingOptions = {
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        'myButton': {
            id: 'myButton',
            symbol: 'circle',
            x: -62,
            symbolFill: '#B5C9DF',
            hoverSymbolFill: '#779ABF'
        }
    }
}
```

But unfortunately it does not provide a lot of expressivity.

Am I able to define a css style and pass it to the global theme or chart set using its **ID** or **CLASS** somehow?

Comment: In your css file just add `#myButton{ your css tweaks }`

Comment: If you need more control over buttons, then how about creating your own buttons? And positioning them over Highcharts chart. Then you can bind click events to separate `chart.exportChart()` methods. See [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.exportChart).

Comment: Thanks.  Amending the css file with an id (i.e. #myButton) does not work in this case.  @PawełFus - appreciate it.  I will likely go his route assuming there are no alternative suggestions; would prefer to use inherent positioning of the library if I can and just style the elements as needed.

Comment: What exactly would you like to change? Open dev-tools and inspect an element. You will see that Highcharts buttons are groups with title/rect/path/text tags. You can get in CSS existing button, for example `$(".highcharts-button:eq(7)")` -> but number 7 will depend on number of buttons already created (in your demo: `1m`, `3m`, `6m`, `YTD`, `1y`, `All`, `exporting button` = 7 items, we count from 0). But still setting CSS options won't be as easy as you may thought. And I'm just mentioning SVG, not VML :)

Comment: I can work with this to start and just to stick to the available attributes.  I was only checking if there was a simple way to pass the style class that perhaps I had overlooked which it doesn't sound like there is at this time.  Thanks I appreciate the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set `class` or `id` of button using [`theme`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.buttons.contextButton.theme) property.

```
buttons: {
    'myButton': {
        symbol: 'circle',
        symbolFill: '#B5C9DF',
        hoverSymbolFill: '#779ABF',
        theme: {
            class: "myButton highcharts-button highcharts-button-normal",
            id: "myDiamondButton"
        }
    }
}
```